# How to get a div to straddle two divs whilst allowing for content increases

Tags: html, css

I have 3 content boxes. The content 1 `blue` and content 2 `grey` are full width, and content3 `orange` one should float above and straddle the others.

How can I have the `grey` content box enlarge so that regardless of the size of the `orange` box, it grows to surround it. In the below snippet the `orange` box overflows the `grey` box.

All 3 boxes must be flexible to content size. e.g if content 1 grows, the `blue` box should grow to accommodate it. Same for content boxes 2 & 3.

I've tried a few solutions: flex, absolute positioning, floats... but I always get stuck trying to get the `grey` box to grow to fit the `orange` one

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  background-color: #68697;
  width: 60%;
}

.top {
  background-color: #042759;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #68697f;
}

.s {
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-1 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.section-3 {
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ff9400;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="s section-1">Content 1<br>...<br>...</div>
    <div class="s section-3">Content 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="s section-2">Content 2<br>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using javascript, this can be achieved.

```js
let sec1 = document.querySelector(".section-1");
let sec2 = document.querySelector(".section-2");
let sec3 = document.querySelector(".section-3");

let sec1H = sec1.clientHeight;
let sec2H = sec2.clientHeight;
let sec3H = sec3.clientHeight;
let sec3MT = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(sec3).marginTop.split("px")[0]);
let sec3MB = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(sec3).marginBottom.split("px")[0]);

let sec3Total = sec3H + sec3MT + sec3MB;
let topOffset = sec3Total - sec1H;

if (topOffset > sec2H) {
  sec2.style.height = (topOffset - sec3MB) + "px";
} else {
  sec2.style.height = sec2H + "px";
}
```

```css
.container {
  color: white;
  background-color: #68697;
  width: 60%;
}

.top {
  background-color: #042759;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.top::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #68697f;
}

.s {
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-1 {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.section-3 {
  float: right;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #ff9400;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div class="s section-1">
      Content 1
      <br>...<br>...
      <br>...<br>...
    </div>
    <div class="s section-3">Content 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="s section-2">
      Content 2
      <br>...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```